# RMI java java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, исключения, rmi

Запускаю из idea Сервер

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, InterruptedException
    {

        CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
        ICustomerService stub = (ICustomerService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(customerService, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        registry.rebind("CustomerService", stub);

        //HibernateSessionFactory.shutdown();
    }
```

Потом клиент

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException
    {
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        ICustomerService stub = (ICustomerService) registry.lookup("CustomerService");
        stub.addNewCustomer("TESTRMI", "TEST", null, null);
    }
```

Вылетает Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at Client.Main.main(Main.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 1):

Все понятно же вроде же. Вы нарушаете модель безопасности и поэтому выбрасывается исключение `AccessControlException`, чтобы побороть его вам надо создать файл `policy` типа:

```
grant codeBase "file:<path>" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

и при запуске указать на него ссылку:

```
java -Djava.security.policy=<filename>.policy
```

[RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/rmi_security_recommendations.html)